# Un-nesting lists within a tibble list column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a tibble with a list column where each element contains a list of length 2.  I have tried to use *unlist()*, *unnest()* and *flatten()* and various other combinations but no luck getting my desired outcome.

A minimal working example is below:

```
df <- tibble(x = c('A', 'B'),
         preds = list(list(Phi = data.frame(time = 1:2, estimate = c('y1', 'y2')),
                           p = data.frame(time = 1:2, estimate = c('y3', 'y4'))),
                      list(Phi = data.frame(time = 1:2, estimate = c('y5', 'y6')),
                           p = data.frame(time = 1:2, estimate = c('y7', 'y8')))))
```

with an expected outcome:

```
output <- tibble(x = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 4),
             grp = c(rep(c('Phi', 'p'), each = 2 ), rep(c('Phi', 'p'), each = 2 )),
             time = rep(1:2, 4),
             estimate = c('y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5', 'y6', 'y7', 'y8'))
```

The following code gets me part way and I could easily include the other columns, but its not correct.

```
df$preds %>% flatten_df()
```

After a day of googling I'm still stuck.  Please point me in some direction.......many thanks!!!

Comment: Try with `df %>%mutate(preds = map(preds, bind_rows, .id = 'grp'))  %>%unnest`

Comment: @KevinArseneau  No offense to you.  I just felt that it is not a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

Building on akrun's already good answer, I offer the following.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    preds = lapply(
      preds, lapply, mutate, estimate = as.character(estimate)
    ) %>%
    lapply(bind_rows, .id = "grp")
  ) %>%
  unnest

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#       x   grp  time estimate
#   <chr> <chr> <int>    <chr>
# 1     A   Phi     1       y1
# 2     A   Phi     2       y2
# 3     A     p     1       y3
# 4     A     p     2       y4
# 5     B   Phi     1       y5
# 6     B   Phi     2       y6
# 7     B     p     1       y7
# 8     B     p     2       y8
```

> **N.B.** The only improvement is the conversion of `estimate` from factor to character. Otherwise, and if this could be addressed in the source data, the map solution by akrun is more concise and easier to reason about.